# Center align is not working even after specifying doctype

Tags: html, css

I referred [CSS align](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp) that refers suggests to use auto margin for center align. I used it but it is not aligning on the center. I checked and verified that doctype is specified.

What is the missing point here?

Note: I am using relative positioning.

CODE

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

        .headerAlert
        {
        float:left;
        width: 100%;
        /*border: 1px solid blue;*/
        display: inline;

        }

        .logoContainer
        {
            float:left;
            width: 50px;
            /*height:250px;*/
            display: inline;
        }

        .vrContainer
        {
            float:right;
            /*border: 2px solid yellow;*/
            display: inline;
        }

        .underlineHeader
        {
         clear:both;
         display: block;
         height:10px;
         width:100%;
         float:left;
         background-color:#632C5A;
         }


          .alert
         {
            padding:50px 0 0 0px;
            /*border:1px solid red;*/
            clear:both;
            display: block;
        }

        .messageContainer
        {
          width:400px;
          border: 1px solid red;
          float: left;
          display: block;
          margin: auto;
          align: center;

        }

        .message
        {
            padding:10px 0 0 0px;
            clear:both; 
            display: block;
            font-weight:bold;
            font-size:20px;
            color:#632C5A;

        }

        .options
        {
            padding:20px 0 0 0px;
            font-size:14px;
        }

    </style>
     </head>
     <body>

    <form name="_ctl0" method="post" action="RedirectAlert.aspx" id="_ctl0">
           <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" value="dDw5NjYas=" />


    <div id="header" class="headerAlert">
        <div id="mainLogo" class="logoContainer">
            <IMG alt="My Inc" src="images/logo.png">
        </div>
        <div id="vcontainer" class="vrContainer">
            <IMG alt="VIT" src="images/logo_v.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="underline" class="underlineHeader">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="alert">


        <div class="messageContainer">




        <div class="message">
            AVC Lts
        </div>

        <div class="options">
        If you still want to use 
            <input type="submit" name="btnContinue" value="Continue" id="btnContinue" />
        </div>

        </div>

    </div>


    </form>
</body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

```
.messageContainer {
    float: left;
    align: center;
}
```

Just remove those lines: `float: left` prevents `margin: auto` centering, and `align: center` is invalid.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jaWEL/1/)

Answer (score 1):

".messageContainer" has all kinds of problems.

1. You're floating it left, which is why its off to the left
2. 'align:center' isn't a thing. Use 'margin: 0 auto" instead

   ```
   .messageContainer { margin: 0 auto; }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
 `align: center;` in CSS doesn't exist.
```

it is :  `text-align: center;` to center text inside

or `margin:auto;` for a block element that has a `width` and **do not** : `float` , or be in `absolute` or `fixed` `position`